# Does ASLR affect the maps file?

Tags: x86, elf, aslr, position-independent-code

Does ASLR affect the maps file? 
AFAIK the default virtual address for the text segment is 0x400000 for 64-bit binaries, but while parsing the */proc/pid/maps* file I found that the OS was apparently using random addresses for the text and data segments, namely:

`564992f16000-564992f17000 r-xp 00000000 00:2c 306966                     /tmp/foo
 564993116000-564993117000 r--p 00000000 00:2c 306966                     /tmp/foo
 564993117000-564993118000 rw-p 00001000 00:2c 306966                     /tmp/foo`

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427).  Distros have started shipping gcc configured to make PIE executables by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main program is PIE (Position-Independent Executable), its load address will be randomized as well.  Even disabling ASLR (say by running under GDB with defaults) will not return it to 0x400000, it will typically be address 0x555555554000 (but this could depend on the kernel).